# ORM mapper for Node.js

Tags: node.js

Is there a cross database ORM mapper for Node.js which provides a consistent API for database access across different relational databases (say MySQL, MS SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle ..). The database page shows different libraries for database access, but I would like to use a library which lets me switch to any database during production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [jugglingdb](https://github.com/1602/jugglingdb/). [RailwayJS](http://railwayjs.com/) project uses it.

Or [sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) (MySQL, SQLite and PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 4):

Might also want to take a look at [bookshelf.js](http://bookshelfjs.org) (MySql, SQLite, PostgreSQL)

It's one of the only ones with transaction support and proper eager loading of relations.

Answer (score 0):

For huge projects: http://bookshelfjs.org/
For small projects: https://github.com/knyga/light-orm

Answer (score -1):

I just wrote my own ORM https://github.com/jbaylina/syncorm

Now there is only one driver for mySQL, but it should be easy to write other drivers for different databases.

The main difference with the rest of ORMs is that the whole database is loaded in memory.

You can access the database as regular javascript objects synchronously. (one object is one record). The objects can be related one each other ina one to many / many to one relation.

It is very useful to use Underscore to iterate thru the objecs.

To modify the objects, you just write in those objects and call commit() to save all the changes to the database in a single transaction.